# Duplicate entry 'bla bla bla bla 'on key 'username'?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I don't know what's wrong with my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dressoholic") or die(mysql_error()); 

if($_POST['form_submitted'] == '1'){

$actkey = mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand();
$birthdate = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];

$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$pswd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$emaill = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email1']);
# gender moet nog gedaan worden!!!
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, fname, lname, email, password, activationkey, bdate, status) VALUES
('$usrname','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$emaill','$pswd','$birthdate','$actkey','verify')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

  echo "An email has been sent to $_POST[email1] with an activation key. Please check your mail to complete registration.";

##Send activation Email

$to      = $_POST['email1'];

$subject = " Dressoholic.com Registration";

$message = "Welcome to our website!\r\rYou, or someone using your email address, has completed registration at Dressoholic.com. You can complete registration by clicking the following link:\rhttp://localhost/dressoholic/register.php?$activationKey\r\rIf this is an error, ignore this email and you will be removed from our mailing list.\r\rRegards,\ Dressoholic.com Team";

$headers = 'From: blabla@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .

    'Reply-To: blabla@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

} 
else {

##User isn't registering, check verify code and change activation code to null, status to activated on success

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if ($queryString == $row["activationkey"]){

       echo "Congratulations!" . $row["username"] . " is now the proud new owner of a Dressoholic.com account.";

       $sql="UPDATE users SET activationkey = '', status='activated' WHERE (id = $row[id])";

       if (!mysql_query($sql))

  {

        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

 }


}
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the exact error:

```
Error: Duplicate entry 'arnold-blabla@gmail.c-1987--22' for key 'username'
```

arnold is the username I entered.
blabla@gmail.com is the e-mail I entered.
1987 the year of birth and 22 the day!

I must say I am a beginner in PHP and MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: make username a varbinary instead of a varchar then you can have 'foo', 'FOO','fOo','foO' etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a unique index in your `users` table on the `username` column. This means that two different users cannot have the same `username`.

Enter a different username or remove the index, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert a user name that already exists (`username` field) on your database. Try selecting a name different from `arnold-blabla@gmail.c-1987--22` or perform an `update` sentence instead of an `insert` if you are just trying to update user information.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a PHP problem, this is a MySQL problem. My guess is that `username` is a primary key on the table `users`. If this is the case, each username must be unique. MySQL is telling you there's a duplicate, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Nima: The message says KEY, not anything about a unique constraint.